# Manage gmail label on iPad

Tags: gmail, ipad

My iPad is configured with GMail (using an Exchange account, not IMAP. But I don't think this is relevant). I would like to create and manage folders in the Mail app.
I noticed that:

- it is sync to my GMail label.
- this feature is not possible in the native Mail app, neither in the official GMail app
- the only way to do it is to use a PC or a Mac (with the GMail desktop version)
- in the GMail mobile web version, I cannot find any button to force desktop version.

What is the simplest workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two workarounds come to mind - find an iOS browser on the app store that will spoof a desktop browser version string and see if gmail will serve up the full version to your iOS device or to use an app to screen share back to an actual desktop browser to gain that functionality.

Comment: this is not the answer I expected but it seems there is no other way right now...

Answer (score 2):

In native mail app, under the "mailboxes" left pane, should be two lists. Top one is "inboxes" and bottom is "accounts". Select gmail account you wish to edit in the "accounts" list (bottom).

You should now see a list of "mailboxes" (apple's wording) which are the same as your gmail labels. Tap "edit" in top right of that pane and tap " new mailbox" on bottom.

You can now type in the name of label you want to create. If you want nested labels, drill into mailboxes below.

This should do the trick.

Comment: This seems promising but I have an error: "Unable to create the mailbox: The mailbox could not be created on the server" (this is not the exact message since I traduce it from french).